# Western Union money order: wrong amount on ticket?

Tags: money-order

I recently bought a money order from Western Union for the first time at my local supermarket. I specified the amount to be $20.4; the amount I was charged with was $21.28, which makes sense. But the printed ticket the cashier gave me also had the amount of $21.28 on it. When I bought USPS money order, it used to show exactly the amount I wanted. I'm in a situation when the money order has to worth exactly $20.4. Can I still use that Western Union money order?

Comment: *the printed ticket the cashier gave me* do you mean the actual money order? Or did you receive a receipt with that amount on it, AND a money order?

Comment: @dwizum the actual money order has $21.28 on it. The receipt has Western Union Money Order Principal = $20.4 and Western Union Money Order Feet = $0.88, to a total of $21.28. Everything looks good except the money order, which confuses me

Comment: Never seen one in real life, but from a quick web-search, if yours has something like `*** PAY EXACTLY $21.28 ***` or `*** PAY EXACTLY TWENTY ONE DOLLARS AND TWENTY EIGHT SENTS ***` on it, then it sounds like a mistake on the part of the cashier.